# How to create a tag with custom properties programmatically?

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to create a [Select2 tag](https://select2.org/tagging) programmatically. I have a function set for the `createTag` config option, which adds a property to the Select2 selection that I later use to distinguish existing options from options that were dynamically created by the user. Tags's options apparently are removed if they are unselected, which I also want. I now want to create a tag programmatically and be able to add my custom property to it.

This works for adding my property to it (to distinguish it from non-user created options) but is there a nicer way? It also doesn't delete the option automatically when it is unselected.

```
const newOption = new Option(searchWord, searchWord, false, true);
$(".search-filter").append(newOption).trigger("change");
// retrieve the just added item and add the property
const selections = $(".search-filter").select2("data");
const newSelection = selections.find((element) => element.id === searchWord);
newSelection.newTag = true;
```